# Decode a JSON Web Token with public key for RSA encoding using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a certificate that gives me the public key for a RSA encoding.
Is there a script that does decode using a public key on a RSA encoding ? I need to decode it and after getting the JSON data, I want to encode it with the same public key and give it back to the back-end.

Comment: The JSON must not be decoded with the public key. It is just a base64 string. You can verify the signature by using the public key. To encode a JWT you need the private key, not the public.

Comment: The point of asymmetric cryptography is that you use one key to encrypt and a different one to decrypt. If all you have is the *public* key, you have been given it so that you can verify signatures, or encrypt data to send to the server; you can't decrypt something with it. If you could, then anyone could, and there'd be no point encrypting it in the first place.

Comment: Well I just figured out, I just want to verify the signed token, and then decode it to get the payload in JSON. That's it, but I'm using RSA encoding, is there a script for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know, so I can't help, but maybe you should update your question or delete this and create a new one with your latest knowledge to better describe what you have and what you like to achieve.

Comment: @Oliver No, I meant what I said. A public key can be used like a secure delivery box: anyone can put things into the box and click the lid shut (encrypt using the public key), but only the owner of the box can open it to get things back out (decrypt using the private key). If there was a public key that could be used to *open* the box, then you might as well not lock the box at all.

Comment: @LiquidSnake JWT supports both signatures and encryption; both are separate from the fact that the content is *encoded* as JSON. If the token is *signed* using RSA, you can use the public key to verify that signature; if the token is *encrypted* using RSA, you *cannot* see its contents without the *private* key. Verifying the signature won't give you access to new information, or get you "closer" to decoding the contents in any way, it will just give you a yes or no as to whether this token was signed by the corresponding private key and has not been tampered with.